# Removing brackets in a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuple as below.

```
>>>> date_lst 

[(2013, 8, 13, 17),
 (2013, 8, 5, 17),
 (2013, 6, 26, 17),
 (2013, 8, 7, 17),
 (2013, 8, 7, 18),
 (2013, 8, 8, 16),
 (2013, 8, 8, 18),
 (2013, 8, 7, 17),
 (2013, 8, 7, 17)]
```

I want this list to print output as below. I would like to remove tuple brackets. What are some possible ways to do so?

```
2013, 8, 13, 17
2013, 8, 5, 17
2013, 6, 26, 17
2013, 8, 7, 17
2013, 8, 7, 18
2013, 8, 8, 16
2013, 8, 8, 18
2013, 8, 7, 17
2013, 8, 7, 17
```

Comment: What are some ways you've tried?

Comment: what is the output? a string?

Comment: @Aprillion it doesn't really matter. I guess string should be a good output to use join as some of the answers

Answer (score 7):

Cast every item in tuple to string, then join them.

```
[', '.join(map(str, x)) for x in date_lst]
```

Comment: @Kroltan it absolutely does not; Python is strongly typed

Comment: This answer is better than the others because it is robust if any lines of the data contain the wrong number of elements (which also makes it generalizable to other questions).

Answer (score 2):

The brackets aren't in the data, so there is nothing to remove. The brackets and parenthesis only show up when you try to print the data. You simply need to extract the data from the list:

```
for data in data_lst:
    print("%s, %s, %s, %s" % data)
```

Comment: this is the top answer !

Answer (score 1):

```
datelist =[(2013, 8, 13, 17),
...  (2013, 8, 5, 17),
...  (2013, 6, 26, 17),
...  (2013, 8, 7, 17),
...  (2013, 8, 7, 18),
...  (2013, 8, 8, 16),
...  (2013, 8, 8, 18),
...  (2013, 8, 7, 17),
...  (2013, 8, 7, 17)]
```

now command like

```py
for date in datelist:
    print(date[0], date[1], date[2], date[3])
```

then you will get

```
2013 8 13 17
2013 8 5 17
2013 6 26 17
2013 8 7 17
2013 8 7 18
2013 8 8 16
2013 8 8 18
2013 8 7 17
2013 8 7 17
```

Comment: Why are you yelling? Your formatting is annoyingly noisy and your explanation non-existent. Please [edit] to improve.

Comment: @Hoppo Your edit improves (appreciatedly) most of the formatting issues. In NOT changing the yelling however you confirm the user in their questionable idea of how to write politely...